# How to implement tap + hold (long press) on Leaflet map?

Tags: leaflet, touch, mousedown

I'm trying to create a tap+hold event to create a new marker location (tap + hold event is only for mobile apps); these event handlers are not working as expected (there is some override taking place)

I tried using map.on('touchstart'...), map.on('mousedown'...), and other variations but event-code only fires after touchend or mouseup completes.

```
me.mapLibObj.on( 'touchstart', function(e) 
{
    if ( ! me.mapTapHoldInterval )
    {
        me.mapTapHoldInterval = setInterval( function() {

            me.mapDownIntvCounter += 1

            if ( me.mapDownIntvCounter > 20 )
            {
                me.defaultCoordinatePoint = [ e.latlng.lat,e.latlng.lng ];
                me.createMyCoordinateMarker( true );

                clearInterval( me.mapTapHoldInterval );
            }

        }, 100 )
    }

} );

me.mapLibObj.on( 'touchend', function(e) 
{
    if ( me.mapTapHoldInterval )
    {
        clearInterval( me.mapTapHoldInterval );
    }
} );
```

Comment: Leaflet already handles long taps to fire `contextmenu` events. Maybe you overlooked that? See https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#map-tap and https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#map-contextmenu

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to look at contextmenu event:
https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#map-interaction-events

```
map.on('contextmenu', (e) => {
  console.log('Lat, Lon:', e.latlng.lat + ',' + e.latlng.lng);
});
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use `mapDownIntvCounter`?

This should be enough (use timeout because you probably want to fire it only once)

```
var mapTapHoldTimeout ;

map.on('touchstart', function() {
   mapTapHoldTimeout = setTimeout(function(){ alert('Touched for 500ms'), 500);
});

//clear interval on touchend or touchmove (or you can calculate distance on touchmove to keep some tolerance)
map.on('touchend,touchmove', function() {
   if ( mapTapHoldTimeout ) {
      clearTimeout(mapTapHoldTimeout );
   }
});
```